# Memcached Ping() doesn't return an error on an invalid server

Tags: go, caching, memcached

I use memcache for caching and the client I use is https://github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache. When I tried initiate new client with dummy/invalid server address and then pinging to it, it return no error.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    m "github.com/bradfitz/gomemcache"
)

func main() {
    o := m.New("dummy_adress")
    fmt.Println(o.Ping()) // return no error
}
```

I think it suppose to return error as the server is invalid. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `New()` call ignores the return value for `SetServers`:

```
func New(server ...string) *Client {
    ss := new(ServerList)
    ss.SetServers(server...)
    return NewFromSelector(ss)
}
```

The `SetServers()` function will only set the server list to valid servers (in
your case: no servers) and the `Ping()` funtion will only ping servers that are
set, and since there are no servers set it doesn't really do anything.

This is arguably a feature; if you have 4 servers and one is down then that's
not really an issue. Even with just 1 server memcache is generally optional.

You can duplicate the `New()` logic with an error check:

```
ss := new(memcache.ServerList)
err := ss.SetServers("example.localhost:11211")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
c := memcache.NewFromSelector(ss)

err = c.Ping()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which gives:

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:11211: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: aah yes, I forgot that memcached is distributed cache.